# ModelAndView returns null SpringBootTest

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-boot-test

I am trying to learn junit tests using spring boot. 
Normally i wouldnt just ask null pointer exception but now i couldnt find what is missing.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@WithMockUser(username = "user", password = "secret", authorities = "USER")
public class OwnersWebMVCTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void testOwners() throws Exception {
        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/owners");
        ResultActions resultActions = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder);

        MvcResult mvcResult = resultActions.andReturn();

        ModelAndView mav = mvcResult.getModelAndView();

        MatcherAssert.assertThat(mav.getViewName(), Matchers.equalTo("owners"));
        MatcherAssert.assertThat(mav.getModel().containsKey("owners"), Matchers.is(true));

    }
}
```

ModelAndView mav = mvcResult.getModelAndView();returns null.

This is my error stack.

```
{
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at demo.petClinic.web.OwnersWebMVCTests.testOwners(OwnersWebMVCTests.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
}
```

Anything helps thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to the controller, not to the test.

**Possible problem** : Your controller is not scanned ! I say this because you expect to have the same GET url and view "owners" => this will fail because it will redirect to itself.

Solution: Please make sure that the controller and the spring boot test have the same package name or import a configuration to scan it.

OwnerController -> src/main/java/**org.test**

TestOwnerController -> src/test/java/**org.test**

Same package name : **org.test**

If you need to have different package names, you can add to your test

```
@ComponentScan("org.owner")
```

-> where org.owner is the package of the OwnerController

Improvement: You can rewrite your test method as

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/owners"))
       .andExpect(model().attributeExists("owners"))
       .andExpect(view().name("view"));
```

Please also change the name of the returned view to not fail :

```
@GetMapping(value = "/owners")
public ModelAndView getOwnersView() {
    return new ModelAndView("view", Collections.singletonMap("owners", new Object()));
}
```

Comment: its not in the same  package 
Because in my folder structure 
there are folders one of them named:"src/test/java".This is where my test class.
Other one is "src/main/java".This is where my controller class.

Comment: OwnerController -> package src/main/java/org.test and TestOwnerController  -> package src/test/java/org.test . Same package name "org.test".

Comment: Well thanks for your interest. I did it thats why i did not write anything